# Solve an integral equation in a shorter time

Tags: integral-equations

Consider the integral equation

$y(x)=x^3+\int _0^x\sin (x-t)y(t) dt$

> Find the value of $y(1)$.

This is a Volterra I.E.I know that in order to solve it I will have to use the technique of Resolvent Kernel but that is very lengthy and it will surely take more than 15 mins to solve it.

I will have to appear in a competitive exam.Is there any easier way to solve this ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139971/volterra-integral-equation-of-second-type?rq=1 can't you use this? (My suggestion may not be the optimal), and formulate it into Jordon canonical form. I suppose you could get your solution much faster.